# What's the active form of "The ball was being kicked by a little boy"?

Tags: passive-voice, active-voice

I believe the active form is "A little boy was kicking the ball" but when i choose that option as my answer for an english test, it was the incorrect option. The test didn't reveal the correct answer though. I still believe that my answer is correct, but i'm very doubtful. Is it correct or incorrect?

Comment: I'd give you a mark for "A little boy was kicking the ball,"  which is correct, but knock off marks for 'i' and 'english'.

Comment: The test is wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is correct.

Passive Voice: The ball was being kicked by a little boy. past continuous/progressive tense

Active Voice: A little boy was kicking the ball.- past continuous/progressive tense

( Passive Voice: The ball is being kicked by a little boy. present continuous/progressive tense

Active Voice: A little boy is kicking the ball.- present continuous/progressive tense

Passive Voice: The ball was kicked by a little boy.- simple past tense

Active Voice: A little boy kicked the ball.- simple past tense

Passive Voice: The ball is kicked by a little boy.-  simple present tense

Active Voice: A little boy kicks the ball.- simple present tense )

Answer (score 0):

'A little boy kicked the ball' is the simplest choice. Perhaps the engine is encouraging you to search for simpler answers.